# RSpec: Testing rescue_from

Tags: testing, rspec

How can I test rescue_from is RSpec?  I'd like to make sure that if one of the exceptions is raised, that the controller correctly sets the flash and does the redirect.  Is there a way to simulate the exception?

```
  rescue_from PageAccessDenied do
    flash[:alert] = "You do not have the necessary roles to access this page"
    redirect_to root_url
  end

  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    flash[:alert] = exception.message
    redirect_to root_url
  end
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming that you have an `authorize!` method that raises the exception, you should be able to do something like this:

```
  describe "rescue_from exceptions" do
    it "rescues from PageAccessDenied" do
      controller.stub(:authorize!) { raise PageAccessDenied }
      get :index
      response.should redirect_to("/")
      flash[:alert].should == "You do not have the necessary roles to access this page"
    end
  end
```

Comment: Even better solution: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs/anonymous-controller

Comment: I don't understand the stub... Seems to me like you are making the controller raise that error in a test. How can you be sure it will raise the error in production if you are just faking it in testing?

Comment: @hamstar This only tests the behavior of the `rescue_from` block. To make sure that `authorize!` raises an error, you'd write another test for that. Presumably this happens in a library (CanCan?) and the author has written the test there.

Comment: With rspec's new ':expect' syntax, it looks like this: `expect(controller).to receive(:authorize!).and_raise(PageAccessDenied)`